# How to solve the differential equation $y'=y(1-y)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value

Up until now, we simply rearranged and integrated both sides, so

$$y'=y(1-y)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y(1-y)$$
$$\frac{dy}{y(1-y)}=dx$$
$$\int\frac{dy}{y(1-y)}=\int dx$$

With partial fraction decomposition one gets

$$\int\frac{dy}{y} +\int\frac{dy}{(1-y)}=\int dx$$

$$\log|y| + C_1 + \log|1-y|+C_2=x+C_3$$

$$\log|y| + \log|1-y|=x+C_4$$

$$|y||1-y|=C_5e^x$$

How do I continue from here?

> Edit: It should be
>
> $$\int\frac{dy}{(1-y)}=-\log|1-y|+C$$

Comment: I think you are ri8,if would have been a case of conditional differential equations than only it would have been continued

Comment: Actually, one should arrive at $$\log|y|-\log|1-y|=x+c$$ hence $$\frac{y}{1-y}=Ce^x$$ hence $$y=\frac{Ce^x}{1+Ce^x}.$$

Comment: @NicholasStull "There's a few cases to deal with" Hmmm... no.

Comment: @TanzWalzer No, the plus sign for the integral is alright, but just after that...

Comment: @Did Oh wow, chain rule, I should go to sleep. Thank you. One last question, why can one remove the absolute value?

Comment: @Did, I know where you and I were differing. I had implicitly assumed $C > 0$, which is not necessary and actually is what introduces the cases that need checked. I've deleted the other comments accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $|y||1-y|=C_5e^x$, and $C_5$ must be positive because it's $e$ raised to a power.  This implies $y(1-y)=C_6 e^x$, where $C_6$ need not be positive.

However, when you divided by $y(1-y)$, you tacitly assumed $y\ne0$ and $1-y\ne 0$.  That means you need to check separately to see if there are solutions consistent with those.

**However:** You neglected the chain rule and should have instead
$$
\frac y{1-y} = C_6 e^x.
$$
That implies:
$$
y = (1-y)C_6e^x
$$
$$
y = C_6e^x - yC_6 e^x
$$
$$
y+yC_6 e^x = C_6 e^x
$$
$$
y(1+C_6 e^x) = C_6e^x
$$
$$
y = \text{etc.}\cdots
$$

Comment: You mean that if I assume $y\neq0$ for instance, then I will only get solutions ehere $y\neq0$, but there might be solutions for which y=0. So I need to make a case distinction?

Comment: $y=0$ and $y=1$ are both constant solutions (equilibrium solutions).

Comment: @NicholasStull So there are no other solutions for which y=0 or y=1 (for some t)?

Comment: You'd need to check whether they are stable or unstable as equilibrium solutions.

Answer (score 0):

A hint: notice that $y(x) = 1$ and $y(x) = 0$ are constant solutions to the DE. Existence and uniqueness then implies that no solution can ever cross these values.

Using this, you could simplify all those absolute values, considering each case... Do you think you can take it from here?